# Why can't we use PUT and GET from a worksheet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

it seem that to use PUT and GET commands for load/unload to/from internal stages we have to use SnowSQL. Why can't we use the Web interface Worksheet(s) ?

Comment: [GET - Usage notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/get.html#usage-notes)

Comment: Because a cloud-based system like Snowflake can’t connect to your local filesystem

Comment: @NickW but I can upload data files directly from local system using web interface (Load Data wizard under Database)

Comment: Don't most browsers have a security restriction on JavaScript that requires the OS file picker to be used to select files for uploading? If not, then the JS could upload files not selected by the user. Since the action requires popping up the OS's file selector, the use of put doesn't work in that environment. It's possible that get could, but it would place the file in the download directory not where the user wants it. A file selector based upload to stage would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nick & Greg mentioned, this is due to the limitation on the browser side, that we do not have direct access to a file or a folder through browser.

I have submitted a feature request to support this, so that a pop up window will ask user to select a location when PUT or GET through the UI.

Not sure it will be accepted or not, but I do hope this can be implemented as I sometimes am forced to switch to SnowSQL to perform GET and PUT as well, which I do feel the inconvenience.

If it ever gets implemented and released, I will update this thread.